# How to extract data from "RemoteCall<BigInteger>" return type function in java/kotlin?

Tags: java, ethereum, geth, web3-java

I'm trying to read balance of an address from erc20 token contract using web3j. I've already generated java equivalent contract file. In this file, A function is returning RemoteCall type of object. Now, how to parse this output so that I can simply get the number (Big integer value)?

When I try to log the output using android log, I get some sort of encrypted output -

org.web3j.protocol.core.RemoteCall@48c4d84

Now I'm totally confused what to do next?

```
public RemoteCall<BigInteger> balanceOf(String param0) {
    final Function function = new Function(FUNC_BALANCEOF, Arrays.<Type>asList(new Address(param0)),
            Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}));
    return executeRemoteCallSingleValueReturn(function, BigInteger.class);
}
```

Expected output is of a Big Integer type number(token balance of the address).

Comment: That output is not encoded. `org.web3j.protocol.core.RemoteCall@48c4d84` is simply the class name and memory reference of the object. It merely means that `toString()` is not implemented on that object.

Comment: Have you read any documentation on the RemoteCall class? What methods are available?

Comment: This page is not found. Also, I've already tried web3j documentation but didn't got any specifics on how to parse the results.

Comment: https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/web3j/protocol/core/RemoteCall.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `send()` on the instance of the `RemoteCall<BigInteger>` that is returned from `balanceOf()`:

```
RemoteCall<BigInteger> remoteCall = someObject.balanceOf(someParameter);
BigInteger result = remoteCall.send();
```